# How can I add boxes to each corner of a radar chart in React using chart.js and react-chartjs-2?

Tags: reactjs, charts

How to create the boxes on the every corner of Redar chart using react-chartjs-2 and chart js

Currently i have the redar chart like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqIB0.png)
and my current configuration is

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Filler,
  Legend,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
  RadialLinearScale,
  Tooltip,
} from "chart.js";
import React from "react";
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "./SpiderChart.scss";
ChartJS.register(
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
type Dataset = {
  data: number[];
  backgroundColor: string;
  borderColor: string;
  borderWidth: number;
  pointBorderColor: string;
  pointBackgroundColor?: string;
  pointBorderWidth: number;
  pointRadius: number;
};
interface SpiderChartProps {
  data: {
    labels: string[];
    datasets: Dataset[];
  }
}

const SpiderChart: React.FC<SpiderChartProps> = ({ data }) => {

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      r: {
        grid: {
          color: "#607080",
   
        },
        angleLines: {
          color: "#607080", 
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "white",
          backdropColor: "transparent",
        },
        pointLabels: {
          color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)",
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <div className="spider-chart" style={{ width: "500px" }}>
      <Radar options={options} data={data} />;
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpiderChart;
```

I want to create the Redar Chart like this like there is a box on every corner of the chart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpUAg.png)